# Ruby different results for "%x{something}" where "something" is quoted or unquoted

Tags: ruby, shell-exec

I'm using Ruby (2.0) `%x{dir}` under Windows 7 to run a DOS `dir` command.  The `dir` being executed is different depending on whether or not `dir` is quoted.

*When the command is bare I get the full output of a DOS `dir` command:*

```
# sends output of cmd back to program
puts 'run %x{dir}'
puts "dir= " + %x{dir}
```

*What I see on the command line:*

```
run %x{dir}
dir=  Volume in drive C is System
 Volume Serial Number is FFFF-FFFF

 Directory of C:\Users\ ...etc...

08/26/2013  09:16 AM    <DIR>          .
08/26/2013  09:16 AM    <DIR>          ..
01/28/2013  02:28 AM            10,958 AJAX RUG Test.tsc
 ...etc...
```

When I quote the `dir` command with either single or double quotes, I get back the output of GnuWin32 `dir.exe` command which is in the `PATH`.  It took me a while to figure out that the GNU `dir` was being run.  What is causing Ruby to use the `dir` built into `CMD.EXE` vs. `c:\PROGRA~2\GnuWin32\bin\dir.EXE` ???

Also, I've just noticed that my "Pickaxe" and "Ruby Cookbook" use the "%x{}" syntax (BRACES), where the online docs use "%x()"  (PARENS) ... is this just a case of general delimiter matching by Ruby?

Comment: Spawning (or not spawning) a sub-shell would be my guess.

Comment: That does make some sense.   The docs for \``cmd`\` say: Returns the standard output of running cmd in a subshell.  I can't find any info on behavioral difference when cmd is quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a peculiarity of Windows, not Ruby. What's going on is this:

Dir is not an executable but a native function of Windows/cmd.exe. (It's part of cmd.exe - so cmd.exe "traps" when you type dir and runs an internal function rather than looking for "dir.exe" or something out on your file path).

When you put something in quotes in cmd, it forces cmd.exe to look for that command on the path, not via it's internal functions.

You can test this by opening a command prompt in Windows and typing a built-in command (that doesn't exist in gnuwin32) such as copy:

```
>copy
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

>"copy"
'"copy"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

If you then create "copy.cmd" file with contents:

> echo copy.cmd executed

when you run, you'll see:

```
>"copy"
copy.cmd executed
```

Make sense? Basically quoting the command you send to the shell (cmd.exe) from Ruby will cause a different interpretation by cmd.exe - it will prevent internal/built-in cmd.exe commands (such as dir and copy) from working, whereas external utils such as xcopy will work fine.